# Mongo aggregate multi match/group

Tags: php, mongodb, match, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I have a data of stores, report_type is every type of data
 - type 3 stored how much money that clients buy and how many transaction.
 - type 5 stored how many people and average age of them.
I need an array like this:

```
"report_type3"       
    (
        [_id] => 2441
        [amountclient] => 3749078452,
        [trans] => 1000
    ), 
    (
        [_id] => 2442
        [amountclient] => 15533754,
        [trans] => 900
    )            
,
"report_type5"
        (
            [_id] => 2441
            [people] => 120,
            [avgage] => 23,
        ),
       (
            [_id] => 2441
            [people] => 120,
            [avgage] => 23,
        )
```

My query looks like this, but it's not working

```
$cursor = $collection->aggregate([
            ['$match' => [ 'id_station' => ['$in' => $store ], 'report_type' => 3,
                            'date' => ['$gte'=> new MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime(strtotime("2017-07-01")*1000), '$lte'=> new MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime(strtotime("2017-08-05")*1000)]  
                         ] 
            ],            
            ['$group' => [
                '_id' => [ 'id_station' => '$id_station', 'receiptid' => '$receiptid' ],
                'amount' => [ '$sum' => '$amount' ]                
            ]], .... *I group by receiptid because there are many items in one clients.*
            [ '$group' => [
                '_id' => '$_id.id_station',
                'amount' => [ '$sum' => '$amount' ],
        'trans' => [ '$sum' => '$trans' ]                
            ]],
        [
                '$project' => [                    
                    'report_type3' => ['_id','$amountclient','$trans']
                ]
            ], 

            ['$match' => [ 'id_station' => ['$in' => $store ], 'report_type' => 5,
                            'date' => ['$gte'=> new MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime(strtotime("2017-07-01")*1000), '$lte'=> new MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime(strtotime("2017-08-05")*1000)]  
                         ] 
            ],
        [ '$group' => [
                '_id' => ['$_id.id_station', 'area_type' => '$area_type'],
                'people' => [ '$sum' => '$people' ],
        'avgage' => [ '$avg' => '$age' ]                
            ]],
            [
                '$project' => [                    
                    'report_type5' => [ '_id', 'people', 'avgage' ]
                ]
            ]
        ]);
```

Could you please help me on this?

Comment: An example of the documents in the collection will significantly increase chances to get an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Also please tag it with the language you are using

Comment: thanks Alex, Im using PHP.